# Google calendar add-on for conference solutions using alternative runtimes doesn't appear in dropdown

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I followed all the steps, by creating google cloud project, enabled the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK and in Alternate Runtimes tab enabled the Add-ons API. I created a new deployment for the add-on and the configuration looks like below:

```
{

  "oauthScopes": [
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.addons.execute", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.addons.current.event.write", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp"],

  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "Waitroom develop addon",
      "logoUrl": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-WuPhRsFGKUc/XCng7m_FIxI/AAAAAAAAAGg/ASH4GCGDMs0d55OZQGCSIQHXjRAKnkeTQCLcBGAs/s400/jitsi-logo-96x96.png"
    },
    "calendar": {
      "conferenceSolution": [{
        "onCreateFunction": "https://wormhole.develop.waitroom.com/v1.0/google/calendar/create-session",
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Waitroom test",
        "logoUrl": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/AM-JKLUkiyTEgH-6DiQP85RGtd_BORvAuFnS9katNMgwYQBJUTiDh12qtQxMJFWYH2Dj30hNsNUrr-kzKMl7jX-Qd0FR7JmVSx-Fhruf8xTPPI-wdsMYez6WJE7tz7KmqsORKBEnBTiILtMJXuMvphqKdB9X\u003ds128-no"
      }],
      "eventUpdateTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "https://wormhole.develop.waitroom.com/v1.0/google/calendar/update-session"
      },
      "currentEventAccess": "READ_WRITE"
    }
  }
}
```

So the issue is after installing the add-on. The add-on appears in the calendar on the sidebar but the add-on doesn't appear in dropdown. Refer the screenshots and the video for more details.

[Add-on appear on sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WMz6.png)
[Add-on doesn't appear in dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeGhQ.png)

I tried reaching out to google support however failed to get the issue resolved. I made sure the suggestions from the support were followed, refer to screenshot below for the suggestions from google support.
[google support response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4iY6.png)

I was expecting to see the add-on to appear in the conference solutions dropdown when creating an event in google calendar.

Comment: I contacted Google Workspace support for the same issue, I was told that this feature is only available for Google Apps Script, and it's expected that it is not available for.  I opted for working with Google Apps Script for my add-on because of this. However, you can request for this feature to be added for  Alternate Runtimes by following the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/workspace-support#developer_product_feedback).

Comment: Thanks @GiselleValladares for confirming the solution. Also curious about your implementation, can you share your implementation specially how you achieved the auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contacting the google workspace support further confirmed that using any other language to develop the add-on this won't be visible in the conference solution section in Calendar. The solution is to create the add-on using Apps Script.

The response from google workplace support was:

> After checking some details here, I can confirm that if you are using any other language to develop the add-on this won't be visible in the conference solution section in Calendar. The solution is to create the add-on using Apps Script. We have tested this behavior and using the Add-on development in Apps Script is recognized in the calendar web UI.

[image: google workspace contact response]

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) The link explains the rationale for this in more detail.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee for guiding, have updated the answer to increase the search-ability. The rationale behind the screenshot was to legitimize the answer as it came from google support team

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).